# Js browserify require from array of strings does not working

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am trying to loop over array of strings and require them with require and for some reason this is not working.

This is working:

```
console.log(require('./siteParts/testis'));
```

This is not:

```
var siteParts = ['testis'];

siteParts.forEach(function(part) {
  console.log(require('./siteParts/' + part));

  Error: Cannot find module './siteParts/testis'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is [status-bydesign], to use the SE terminology. Browserify uses naive parsing of the text, and only searches for a normal `require('some module name')`. Anything dynamically parsed isn't going to be included.